# how to check continously for gps fixed android

Tags: android, gps

I am using GPSStatus.Listner

```
case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:

    if ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - GPSManager.mLastLocationMillis) < 3000) {
            isGPSFix = true;
        } else
            isGPSFix = false;
```

calling this method every second to get the status. 
But sometimes it hangs and always returns gps false.
I am not getting the reason why?

Comment: use a location listener ; which has four inputs ; there u can add a provider, it can be either network/ GPS/ u can also fetch from criteria obj. and also u can set a time duration for which the provider responds; not to forget make the minDistance param = 0; otherwise the provider wont respond to the time duration mentioned in the listener.

Comment: @DJphy Thanks for reply. May you please provide me any link for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/will-quast/AndroidGpsSample/blob/master/src/com/example/gpssample/MainActivity.java) is a great example of use of LocationManager and GPSStatus.Listener. With MINIMUM_UPDATE_TIME and MINIMUM_UPDATE_DISTANCE you can set how often you want location updates.

Comment: Did that answer help you?